# How to solve "Project is not configured" problem when opening the Unreal Engine project in CLion?

Tags: c++, clion, unreal-engine4

When I have opened my Unreal Engine project in CLion, it warns me: "Project is not configurated".

[image]

I suppose it is why autocompletes does not work.

All toolchains is my IDE seems to be set up properly:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Also I have noticed that is some cases the "Project is not configured" message does not appear even is to open the project for the first time ([example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fetFJUsfY2c&t=379s)).

Comment: What happens when you push the "configure cmake button" in your first image?